# How do I handle database columns with reserved characters in SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm somewhat new to SQLAlchemy ORM, and I'm trying to select and then store data from a column within a view that has a forward slash in the name of the column.

The databases are mapped using the following:

```
source_engine = create_engine("...")
base = automap_base()
base.prepare(source_engine, reflect=True)
metadata = MetaData(self.engine)
table_1 = Table("table_1", self.metadata, autoload=True)
```

The second destination table is mapped the same way.

Then, I connect to this database, and I'm trying to select information from columns to copy into a different database:

```
source_table_session = Session(source_engine)
dest_table_session = Session(dest_engine)

table_1_data = table_1_session.query(table_1)
for instance in table_1_data:
    newrow = dest_table.base.classes.dest_table()
    newrow.Column1 = instance.Column1 # This works fine, column has normal name
```

But then, the problem is that there's a column in the view with the name "Slot/Port"

With a direct query, you can do:

```
select "Slot/Port" from source_database;
```

But in ORM, you can't just type:

```
    newrow.Slot/Port = instance.Slot/Port
```

or

```
    newrow.'Slot/Port' = instance.'Slot/Port'
```

That isn't going to be correct, and the following doesn't work either:

```
    newrow.SlotPort = instance.SlotPort
```

AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'SlotPort'

I have no control over how columns are named in the source database.

I find the SQLAlchemy documentation to be generally fragmented (only showing small snippets of code) and confusing, so I'm not sure if this is kind of thing is addressed or not. Is there a way to get around this limitation, or perhaps if the columns are already mapped to a valid name without a slash or a way to do so?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `instance['Slot/Port']` should work.

Comment: @DeepSpace hmm...not quite, I get `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str` for that. I also tried double quotes.

Comment: Then try `getattr(instance, 'Slot/Port')`. If that still doesn't work, try to print `dir(instance)` and look for the relevant attribute, it might have been renamed to use a valid character.

Comment: Awesome, @DeepSpace. A little more built-in function research got me to where I need to be: `setattr(newrow, 'Slot/Port', getattr(instance, 'Slot/Port'))`

Comment: It's possible to use reflection events to alter the key given to the column as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215759/sqlalchemy-reflecting-tables-and-columns-with-spaces

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DeepSpace for helping me find the answer.

Instead of

```
newrow.whatever = instance.whatever
```

I needed:

```
setattr(newrow, 'Slot/Port', getattr(instance, 'Slot/Port'))
```