# SQLAlchemy MetaData().reflect() with column attribute lowercase

Tags: python, reflection, sqlalchemy, orm

is there a way to force column attribute name to lowercase using sqlalchemy reflection?

```
metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(session.conn)
```

AS IS:

```
metadata.tables['table'].columns.DATARIF
```

DESIRED:

```
metadata.tables['table'].columns.datarif
```

Comment: Some dialects will automatically perform "name normalization". Which dialect are you using?

Comment: sql server, oracle, postrgresql and db2. the problem is that I would like to use the same code for all db. sql server save column as DATARIF, oracle as datarif.

Comment: There's an event you can use to do that (normalize the column key), and I think there's an existing Q/A here that shows how to use it. Trying to find it.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215759/sqlalchemy-reflecting-tables-and-columns-with-spaces

Comment: @event works! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def import_db_tables(self):
        self.set_metadata(sa.MetaData())
        @event.listens_for(sa.Table, "column_reflect")
        def reflect_col(inspector, table, column_info):
            column_info['key'] = column_info['name'].lower()
        self.metadata.reflect(self.conn)
```